# MS SQL 2014 cross-database access does not work as I expect

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have two databases. One with data and one with stored procedures. A user should not be able to read data directly, but only through stored procedures.
Flags "Cross-Database Ownership Chaining" are enabled on the server and on the all databases.

As SA I am doing:

```
use data_db
create table dbo.t(....)
insert into t values(....)


use sp_db

create procedure dbo.readt as
   select * from data_db.dbo.t

grant execute on dbo.readt to user1
```

Now I reconnect as user1

```
execute sp_db.dbo.readt
```

and I am getting an error:

> The server principal "user1" is not able to access the database
>   "data_db" under the current security context.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.

My initial desire was that regular users were not be able to do '*use data_db*' at all, since they are not allowed to read any data from *data_db* directly.
Apparently the server cannot work like that... Strange but ok.

as SA:

```
use data_db
grant connect to user1
```

The user is now able to do '*use data_db*' command, but nothing else.
The CDOC finally works!

Answer (score 1):

You need `execute as`:

```
create procedure dbo.readt
   with execute as owner
as
begin
   select * from data_db.dbo.t;
end;
```

The stored procedure then has the permissions of the whoever created it, rather than the user calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if your user is mapped to the Database you are trying to log into.